# What does the backslash mean in the following piece of code?

Tags: c

I can't apprehend the use of backslash in this piece of code, does it act as an operator in this scenario ?

```
#define foreach(item, array) \
for(int keep = 1, \
        count = 0,\
        size = sizeof (array) / sizeof *(array); \
    keep && count != size; \
    keep = !keep, count++) \
  for(item = (array) + count; keep; keep = !keep)
```

Comment: It's the line continuation character. This is certainly a duplicate, but am struggling to find it.

Comment: @Bathsheba, Can we use a backslash in the normal code in the same way as in macros ?

Comment: Yes͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the same as if you had written it on a single line.

When writing a `#define`, you can't use line breaks in the middle of a definition. But, putting it all on a single line would hamper readability. Hence, this is what is done usually.

Yes, it works for code as well, because the C specification states:

> Each instance of a backslash character () immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>   form logical source lines.

Comment: Will that be the case too if we use the backslash in the normal code as well ?

Comment: @SandeepGusain Yes, it does. Have updated the answer.